# Protocol version from JavaScript Fetch responses

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

I was just playing with [`Fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) and noticed it seemed impossible to get the [protocol version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#HTTP_Responses) from the response [start line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#Start_line). During an HTTP request the first line of a response could look like this:

`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Basically, I am looking for a way to get the `HTTP/1.1` part of the first line.

I was able to find the `Response.status` and `Response.statusText` properties, but is there a way to get either the first line (which does not seem to be part of `Response.headers`) or the protocol version directly?

Comment: It looks like you are right. You might be able to infer the protocol through other elements, but it doesn't look to me like there's a property there.

Comment: That piece, as well as some response headers, aren't available to page javascript.

Comment: No, `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequests` are http apis. They do not let you read the underlying raw tcp stream. Why would you care?

Comment: It was just to troubleshoot issues. I thought it could be useful to have the full response in the logs in case of errors. It looks like this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **No**, it's not possible.

I could actually not find details on the "long answer" and why this information was unavailable.